# Should light temperatures be equal in all rooms?

Tags: lighting, led

We have different compact fluorescent lamps and LEDs with different color temperatures in our flat and I found it to be unpleasant to have a blueish light in the bedroom and a yellower one in the hallway. Should I equalize it and use, for instance, 2700K lights in all rooms or is it better to have a lower color temperature in the bedroom and a higher one in the working room?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I say it's personal preference. We found we like daylight 5000K better so as bulbs burn out I get new LEDs (previously CFLs) that are daylight. Eventually they'll all be changed but for now they are mixed and we don't mind.

What's your preference? That's what I'd go with.